# How to find coefficients of parabola based on graph?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, quadratics

I have a quadratic graph.

I know that I have the following options:

Vietes formula, vertex (x0,yo), the quadratic equation to get x1,x2. Somehow I don't see how I would get the coefficients A and B. 
The C coefficient is C=3 as it can be read from the graph easily.

How should I tackle the problem?

Just to note that this graph is the function derivative of a previous graph, in other words

$${f(x)'}=Ax^2+Bx-3$$

The problems says that I have to find $$f(x)$$
I know that I have to integrate and therefore easily get the equation but I need the coefficients.

**Image of the derivative graph:**
[image]

Comment: you have $$f(2)=5$$ and $$f(-2)=1$$

Comment: Why is $c=-3$. ?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner $f'$

Comment: It seems I missed that, tnx now that s easy

Comment: the plot says $g$. is $g=f'$ or $g=f$ or $g=f''$ or $g= ???$

Comment: @ArchisWelankar because the parabola is moved vertically by -3

Comment: But its slightly away from y axis the diagram isnt quite accurate.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar it still moved by -3 it doesnt matter if the vertex does not pass through -3

Comment: @ArchisWelankar C is the y-intercept, not the minimum.

Comment: Okay those are unit squares thanks got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the equation with two unknowns $f'(x)=Ax^2 + Bx - 3$ and from the graph you know $(2,5)$ and $(-2,1)$ are points on $f$. So you have a system of equations,

\begin{align*}
5 &= A(2)^2 + B(2) - 3 \\
1 &= A(-2)^2 + B(-2) - 3
\end{align*}

So $A=\frac 3 2$, $B=1$ meaning $f'(x)=\frac 3 2 x^2 + x - 3$ and $f(x) = \frac 1 2 x^3 + \frac 1 2 x^2 - 3x + c$

Answer (score 1):

you will get
$$4a+2b=8$$ and $$4a-2b=4$$ form here we get $$a=\frac{3}{2}$$ and $$b=1$$

Answer (score 1):

You have $f'(-2)=1$, $f'(0) = -3$, $f'(2)= 5$.

So
$$f'(-2)=1=A(-2)^2+2B(-2)-3$$
$$f'(2)= 5=A(2)^2+B(2)-3$$

and you can solve.

Comment: Simple and perfect